# Separando substrings e armazenando em variáveis C++

Tags: c++, string

Então, criei uma função que lê um arquivo de texto e guarda, linha a linha, em um vetor de strings retirando as vírgulas.

A entrada do arquivo é :

```
add $t2, $t3, $t4
sub $t5, $t6, $t7
addi $t6, $t7, 4
```

Aplicando a função:

```
void openFile(char** filePipe, std::vector<std::string> *lines){
std::ifstream filePine;
std::string line;

filePine.open(*filePipe);
if (!filePine.is_open()){
    std::cout << "Arquivo " << *filePipe << " não foi encontrado" << std::endl;
}else{
    std::cout << "Arquivo " << *filePipe << " foi encontrado" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Prosseguindo operação: " << std::endl;
    while(!filePine.eof()){
        getline(filePine, line);
        //std::cout << line << std::endl;
        line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(),','), line.end());
        lines->push_back(line);
    }
}
filePine.close();
}
```

Me gera essa saída:

```
add $t2 $t3 $t4
sub $t5 $t6 $t7
addi $t6 $t7 4
```

Agora eu preciso separar cada substring dessa em 4 vetores diferentes, todos eles de acordo com a string0 (add, sub, addi, etc) pois nem todos os comandos possuem 4 substrings (no caso eu adicionaria um nullptr naqueles que que tiverem menos que quatro).

Só que eu não estou encontrando algo que sirva de split para isso. Poderiam me ajudar?

Exemplo: prático:
Na entrada:

```
add $t2 $t3 $t4
```

Eu preciso que o programa armazene:

```
std::vector<std::string> instruc = add;
std::vector<std::string> op1 = $t2;
std::vector<std::string> op2 = $t3;
std::vector<std::string> op3 = $t4;
```

E assim sucessivamente para cada linha de entrada, dando push_back() no respectivo vetor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira é essa, considerando que as strings estejam separadas apenas por espaços. Devem existir outras.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // string de entrada, com varias substrings separadas por espacos
   string tokenString { "aaa bbb ccc" };

   // cria um stream de strings baseado na string de entrada
   istringstream ss { tokenString };

   // vetor onde serao guardadas as substrings extraidas do stream de strings
   vector<string> tokens;

   // variavel que recebera' cada substring extraida do stream de strings
   string token;

   // separando as substrings e guardando num vetor de strings
   while (ss >> token)
      tokens.push_back(token);

   // mostrando as substrings que foram separadas
   for (const string& token: tokens)
       cout << "* " << token << endl;
}
```

PS. I love C++ :)

Answer (score 0):

O C++ aparentemente não possui uma função padrão de split assim como no Java ou Javascript, no entanto você pode construir uma da seguinte forma:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strings;
    istringstream f("denmark;sweden;india;us");
    string s;    
    while (getline(f, s, ';')) {
        cout << s << endl;
        strings.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Este código foi retirado dessa pergunta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g

Acredito que isso resolva o problema.